# How to delay form submit prestashop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i'm developing prestashop carrier module.inside mycarrier i have two radio buttons(`now`,`schedule`)
when user select `now` i,m getting current datetime.when user select schedule i'm prompt calender to pick datetime.

problem :

when user select one of radio button,form will submit immediately.but i want form to wait until user pick date from calendar.

how can i delay my form submission?

```
<form class="clearfix" id="js-delivery" data-url-update="{url entity='order' params=['ajax' => 1, 'action' => 'selectDeliveryOption']}" method="post">   
  <button type="submit" class="continue btn btn-primary pull-xs-right" name="confirmDeliveryOption" value="1">
      {l s='Continue' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
  </button>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: you need to intercept form submit event and check for the checkbox, then if it needs the timepicker return false to delay form submit, or return true to continue submit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to intercept form submit event and check for the checkbox, then if it needs the timepicker return false to delay form submit, or return true to continue submit.

```
document.querySelector("#js-delivery").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    var isValid = "[write your delay clause]"
    if(!isValid){
        e.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```